# Custom HTML tag for Interpolated value

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I'm using react-i18next, verion 11.16.1. React, version 18.2.0.

My translation file looks like this (loaded from web):

```
{
  ...
  'U.Temperature': '{temperature} °C',
  'U.Voltage': '{voltage} V',
  ...
};
```

I'm using `Trans` component in order to translate. In DOM i get translations an plain value.

```
<Trans i18nKey={translation} values={{ [unit]: convertedValue }} />;
```

Is there any way to make an interpolated value as HTML element, without modifying the translation object? I mean to have something like this:

```
<Trans i18nKey={translation} values={{ [unit]: <span className='test'>{convertedValue}</span> }} />;
```

In order to get in DOM something like this:

```
<span class='test'>12</span> °C
```